# Is there a jQuery date formatter plugin that handles multiple time zones and proper daylight savings time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, timezone, dst

I live in Hawaii where there is no Daylight Savings Time. I'm trying to show a world clock that displays dates and times from different time zones, but I also need it to properly calculate the DST offset. The limitation is that I must use the client time, as the application will not be able to get internet access. Is there a jQuery plugin that can handle this, or do I have to write it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it HAVE to be a jQuery plugin?

There is a project on github that prototypes the Javascript Date object to be able to handle [timezone keys](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js)

Regardless of how you do it, you will have to get the tzinfo database to work with your script (well, that's the only way I know of that will give you robust information about DST around the world). I have no personal experience of the library I linked above, but people seem to mention it from time to time, and it is the only pure JavaScript lib I have found to the tzinfo database.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_time_zone_offset( ) {
     var current_date = new Date( );
     var gmt_offset = current_date.getTimezoneOffset( ) / 60;
     return gmt_offset;
}
```

Comment: I think you misread my question. There's no DST here in Hawaii, so that code will fail when there's DST on the mainland.